# Download sample data from stream input

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

In developing/debugging a Stream Analytics job Query, I can either upload sample data, or capture a sample from the incoming stream.
When capturing, I remember there was an option to download the captured data and save it to my local machine. Now I do not see that option. I thought it was simply clicking on the document icon next to the ellipsis, but this does not work.

Is this still possible?
If not, what is the alternative technique to save/inspect the incoming data to a job?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. This is likely the "new way", and I missed the memo. 
Opening the stream job's Inputs, clicking on the desired input. Within the "Input Details" blade, there is a "Sample Data" button at the top. Clicking that starts a sampling, with option to download the sampled data when complete.

So the capability was removed from the context of the query, and added to the context of the input.

Hope this saves someone else some head scratching time.

-John

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sampling from the input via the portal, you can tap into the hub for the input via [Service Bus Exporer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer). Despite the name, you can use it for IoT Hub, Event Hub or Service Bus. It allows you to save the output. I use this often for realtime monitoring of both the inputs and outputs while working on ASA jobs.